# My miredo client don't work after upgrading to 15.10

Tags: networking, ipv6

I have used miredo in 15.04 ,and it works very well.But after I upgrad my Ubuntu to 15.10 yesterday,it doesn't work any more.Here is some information.

```
$ ifconfig teredo
teredo    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet6 addr: 2001:0:53aa:64c:34f5:fbcf:8a68:fd02/32 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::ffff:ffff:ffff/64 Scope:Link
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1280  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:144 (144.0 B)

$ service miredo status 
● miredo.service - Teredo IPv6 tunneling
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/miredo.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since 日 2015-10-25 14:56:09 CST; 20min ago
  Process: 3622 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/miredo-checkconf -f /etc/miredo/miredo.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3625 (miredo)
   CGroup: /system.slice/miredo.service
           ├─3625 /usr/sbin/miredo -f
           ├─3626 /usr/sbin/miredo -f
           └─3627 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/miredo/miredo-privproc 4

10月 25 14:56:09 muffin-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Teredo IPv6 tunneling...
10月 25 14:56:09 muffin-ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Teredo IPv6 tunneling.
10月 25 14:56:09 muffin-ubuntu miredo[3625]: Starting...
10月 25 14:56:09 muffin-ubuntu miredo[3625]: miredo[3625]: Starting...
10月 25 14:56:10 muffin-ubuntu miredo[3626]: New Teredo address/MTU
10月 25 14:56:10 muffin-ubuntu miredo[3626]: Teredo pseudo-tunnel started
10月 25 14:56:10 muffin-ubuntu miredo[3626]:  (address: 2001:0:53aa:64c:34f5:fbcf:8a68:fd02, MTU: 1280)
10月 25 14:56:10 muffin-ubuntu miredo[3625]: miredo[3626]: New Teredo address/MTU
10月 25 14:56:10 muffin-ubuntu miredo[3625]: miredo[3626]: Teredo pseudo-tunnel started
10月 25 14:56:10 muffin-ubuntu miredo[3625]: miredo[3626]:  (address: 2001:0:53aa:64c:34f5:fbcf:8a68:fd02, MTU: 1280)
```

All those info seem normal,but it just doesn't work,like this:

```
$ping6 ipv6.google.com
connect: Network is unreachable
muffin@muffin-ubuntu:~$ ping6 2001:4860:4860::8888
connect: Network is unreachable
```

And also this website(www.test-ipv6.com) shows that miredo is not working.

[image]

Besides,I have uninstalled ufw.And I have noticed that "TX bytes" is always "114B",and it doesn't change at all.

So, is there anything wrong in settings? Or how can I get more Info about this problem?

Comment: Amazing that you got it working well. Teredo is a complex, unstable and unreliable protocol for connecting to the IPv6 internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it completely wrong but I'm sure will save nervous system dozens Ubuntu users.

So, I faced miredo issue twice:

1. service starts before domain names had been resolved,
2. default route for ipv6 traffic is the same as for ipv4.

I'm just an user and I don't know why happens it. But I contrived to solve the issue.

type in terminal

```
sudo vi /etc/rc.local
```

insert before `exit 0` these lines

```
sleep 3
service miredo restart

sleep 3
ip -6 route add default dev teredo
```

Then save the file and exit from vi editor. Reboot system.

Enjoy!

---

Recently I noticed miredo don't works after suspend mode. So, I had been forced make some additions.

`cd /etc/pm/sleep.d`

`sudo vi 49_ipv6_miredo`

write inside:

```
    #! /bin/sh

    case $1 in
         suspend|suspend_hybrid|hibernate)
            # No need to do anything here
            :
            ;;
         resume|thaw)
            sleep 5
            ip -6 route add default dev teredo
            ;;
    esac`
```

save and exit (:wq), change access permissions

`sudo chmod 755 49_ipv6_miredo`

that is all